# Jquerymobile textBox - onChange Event - Does not work in Operamobile browsers

Tags: jquery-mobile, onchange

I am developing the sample apps using the jquerymobile alpha 4.1. In my design, I have to get the value from textbox while enduser change the value of control.

So I am using the following code.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="username" > </input>
```

JS :

```
$("#username").live("change" , function() {
    alert("hai"+ $("username").val()); 
});
```

It is working fine in the iphone-safari browser, Android , blackberrry native browsers.

But It does not work in the Operamobile- 11 and Operamobile 10. ( It could not detect the this events.)

Please share your suggestion. Shall I use any other event for avoiding this error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HYsbg/3/)

Try this:

```
$("#username").live("change" , function() {
    alert("hai "+ $("#username").val()); 
});
```

instead of this:

```
$("username").live("change" , function() {
    alert("hai"+ $("username").val()); 
});
```

Alternative: ( Without the live() ): [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HYsbg/4/)

```
$("#username").change(function() {
    alert("hai "+ $("#username").val()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Phill.  But It does not work in the operamobile 10 and 11 browsers. Other browsers are working fine in this mechanism.

Comment: @Girija did you solve this?  I have same issue where Opera Mobile 10 does not fire onchange events?